# Help identifying/using some weird pin headers

Tags: pins, header

EE student who's a little new to the hardware side of electronics here.

I could use some advice on how to use these things- I assumed they were pin headers, but I might be wrong about that.

They almost look like regular female pin headers (like [these](https://solarbotics.com/product/fpin12-2mm/?cid=2&gclid=Cj0KCQjwh7zWBRCiARIsAId9b4rCd8kPz7Hs9zhFK3Expcq6qkwEJJY7n9iBcMjwSPtEgf8iT1a-8xsaAk4DEALw_wcB), which are what I wish I had), but the pins on the bottom are bent out at right angles. The pitch is 2mm. I'm fairly sure they came as extras with some XBee modules, but I wasn't the person who ordered the parts for this group project so I'm not 100% positive where they came from.

[image: Top view]

[image: Bottom view]

The goal is to be able to solder them onto a prototyping board, but I'm not sure how to do that with the bent legs. I've tried bending the legs to point straight down, but they break extremely easily and the few that didn't break are still too short to go through my prototyping board.

Does anyone know how these are supposed to be used? Are these even usable pin headers or have I misidentified them completely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are pretty bog standard surface mount 2mm pitch female header. You are correct that they are suitable for use with xBee's which use 2mm male header.

They are designed to be soldered onto the surface of a PCB to pads as pictured below. As such the legs are intentionally bent out in the way they are

[image: SMD Header]

Unless you need 2mm header for something, ditch them and get some standard 0.1" though-hole header.